# Google play multi-player, how to receive the invite when the app is closed

Tags: android, google-play-services

The problem I found with google play services (multi-player) is that the invitee has to have the app open already in order to respond to the invite.

Is there no way I can have the invite appear on the invitee phone even if the app is closed (background)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send an invite to a player with the game running, the [OnInvitationReceivedListene](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/OnInvitationReceivedListener.html)r should be triggered from inside the game.

If you send an invite to a player with the game NOT running, Google Play Services on his phone should receive a request. The player can then accept or decline that invitation.

If he accepts the invitation, your game will be launched, and the [ConnectionCallbacks.onConnected()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks#onConnected%28android.os.Bundle%29) will be triggered with a bundle containing the [GamesClient.EXTRA_INVITATION](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#EXTRA_INVITATION#EXTRA_INVITATION). Using this [invitation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitation.html) object, you can join the appropriate room.

Please note that I already encountered a bug in **Google Play Services SDK ver. 3.2.65** - in which the bundle in the onConnected callback doesn't return the invitation id.
This seems to be fixed in **4.0.30**.

Comment: Did this actually work? In my case the app does get launched from the invitation notification but it doesn't seem like onConnected() is getting called.

Comment: @Shakkalakka This seems to launch my MainActivity. My multiplayer gaming `Activity` is a separate one and therefore MainActivity doesn't implement `onConnected` etc. meaning no trigger. Is there a way to make it launch the multiplayer `Activity` if an invitation is accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and I had to address additional conditions. more over, many links in the above answers were broken. So I had to do it on my own and this is how i  did it.
*NB: I was using gamehelper class obtained from sample games. make appropriate changes*

```
public void checkInvites()
{
    if(!mHelper.isSignedIn()) return;
    PendingResult<LoadInvitationsResult> invs = Games.Invitations.loadInvitations(mHelper.getApiClient());
    invs.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LoadInvitationsResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onResult(LoadInvitationsResult list) {
            if(list==null)return;
        if(list.getInvitations().getCount()>0)invitationInbox();
        }});
}
```

This callbacks `invitationInbox()` method which opens the invitation inbox.

```
 public void invinbox() 
 {       
         Intent intent = Games.Invitations.getInvitationInboxIntent(mHelper.getApiClient());
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX);    }        
    }
```

The advantage is that you can call `checkInvites()` from anywhere anytime to check if there are any pending invitations.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Invitation Acceptance Phase documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#3_invitation_acceptance_phase):

> The player who initiated the game is automatically joined to the room. Invitees to a multiplayer game will see a notification displayed on mobile devices to prompt them to join the game. If they accept the invitation, your app must issue an API call to join the player to the room corresponding to that invitation.
>
> Play Games services notifies the invitees via the [ConnectionCallbacks.onConnected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. The callback method is passed a `connectionHint` Bundle. Your app can retrieve an [Invitation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitation.html) object from this Bundle by using the [GamesClient.EXTRA_INVITATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#EXTRA_INVITATION) key.

As explained in the [Invite Players option documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#invite_players_option), you can use the selected invitees returned from [GamesClient.getSelectPlayersIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getSelectPlayersIntent%28int,%20int%29) with [RoomConfig.Builder.addPlayersToInvite()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.Builder.html#addPlayersToInvite%28java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) to send invitations to the selected players upon room creation which will appear as notifications on other players devices.

Comment: If you notice, it says that play game services will notify the invitee via callback  onConnected. So the app has to be running for the code to the execute as it is not a broadcast receiver that will execute when the app is closed. Also it is not a status bar notification

Comment: @Snake - they're just describing one of the many places you need to [handle invitations](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#handling_invitations) and you do receive notifications in the status bar unless you've registered a [OnInvitationReceivedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/OnInvitationReceivedListener.html) as explained in the [handling invitations during gameplay section](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#during_gameplay).

Comment: @Snake - perhaps you are not not calling [GameClient.unregisterInvitationListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#unregisterInvitationListener())?

Comment: But it says in the doc that when the user sign in, I have to check pending invitation. That tells you that it is more of a polling mechanism rather than push notification. If it is push notification,and the use clicks on the status notification, what code will execute?  I don't see any mention of notification receiver (broadcast). Or I am missing missing the point perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I see that onConnected() in my Activity class is not called but it does call the onConnected() method in the GameHelper class.